# flask - Get request referrer endpoint

Tags: python, flask, request, endpoint

I need a way to get the request referrer endpoint from Flask. I need it to be able to have the user change language on the website, and then be redirected to that same page with the updated language.

### views.py

```
@app.route('/<language>/change')
def change_language(language):

    if language == 'fr':
        _language = 'en'
    elif language == 'en':
        _language = 'fr'

    # makes a response and assigns cookie
    resp = make_response(
        redirect(url_for(request.referrer.endpoint, language=_language)))
    resp.set_cookie('lang', _language)
    return resp
```

Let's say the user has clicked "change language" from the login route below:

```
@bp.route('/<language>/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login(language):
    return render_template('/auth/login.html')
```

I need them to be redirected here, but with the right language. I left the broken code above (`request.referrer.endpoint` doesn't exist) to show what I'm ideally trying to do.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `request.referrer`? It will give you the entire URL, you can parse the endpoint from that.

Comment: The endpoint would be in the form of `/en/login`. Which would work, as long as the last word in the url matches the function (or explicit endpoint) in Flask. I was hoping for something that could be more dynamic.

Comment: AFAIK `url_for()` references the internal names (e.g. `change_language`) instead of the actual urls, so getting the endpoint in there is moot unless you have a dictionary of some sort to redirect.  Perhaps it's easier to just parse the referrer and replace the language accordingly.